# determine period of given signal

Tags: periodic-functions

i would like to compute Fourier coefficients from given signal,and i have following picture

[image]

i need to know  period,just to make sure that i am not making mistake,period  should be  $\frac {T} {2}$ right?because starting from $0$ point,it repeats again peak after $\frac {T}{2}$ second am i right or i am making some mistake?thanks in advance

Comment: No, it sholud bt $T$

Comment: aa ,i see,so fourier  coeficients i should take from $0$ to $T$ right?

Comment: by the way DC coefficient of the Fourier series  should be $1$ right?because we  would have  $\frac {1}{T} *\int^{T}_{0} 1*dt$

Comment: no i made mistake it should be $1/4$

Comment: could you help me please to calculate fourier coefficients,i am lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take your period as $[-T/2,T/2]$ and over a period your function can be written as 
$$
x(t)=\begin{cases}
1, & \frac{-T}{4}\leq t\leq\frac{T}{4}\\
0, & else
\end{cases}
$$
 So the coefficient $a_0$ is:
$$a_{0}=\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}1dt=\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/4}^{T/4}1dt=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: why half of period ?

Comment: yes that i have got for  $a_0$,for $a_k$?

Comment: For $a_k$ evaluate the integral $\frac{2}{T}\int_{-T/4}^{T/4}cos(\frac{2\pi.t.n}{T})dt$

Answer (score 1):

the period is T here, as it takes T to reach the same phase in your signal